# How do I handle a view that loads for a very long time?

Tags: .net, mvvm, async-await, avaloniaui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am trying to write a game in Avalonia 11 with Community Toolkit MVVM.

The game has a `MainView` which acts as a router, and two child views `TitleView` and `GameView` with buttons for navigating between one another. Clicking the buttons sends a message to the `MainViewModel` to update its `Content` property. (source: [Navigate Views | Avalonia Docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/todo-list-app/navigate-views))

The `GameView` is also somewhat complex - it contains a lot of child elements with SVGs in them. Because of this, the application freezes for a long time when navigating from `TitleView` to `GameView`. It's bearable on desktop, but takes a super long time on browser.

I have introduced a loading overlay on top of the `MainView`'s content control with the aim of displaying it while the child view is loading using `Task.Run()`, but the results are not what I expected.

I have two problems:

1. There is still visible stutter during the navigation, and sometimes the UI freezes on the old content even *before* displaying the loading overlay, which makes the feature useless
2. It does not work on browser at all - the contents of `Task.Run()` are not executed.

Which makes me wonder if I'm even approaching this from the right angle?

###### MainView.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
    <Border
        Background="Black"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}">
        <i:Icon
            Animation="Pulse"
            Value="fa-spinner" />
    </Border>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

###### MainViewModel.cs

```cs
private ViewModelBase _content = (ViewModelBase)titleViewModel;

private bool _isLoading;

public bool IsLoading
{
    get => _isLoading;
    set => SetProperty(ref _isLoading, value);
}

public ViewModelBase Content
{
    get => _content;
    set => SetProperty(ref _content, value);
}

// ...

public async void Receive(LeaveGameRequest message)
{
    IsLoading = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Content = (ViewModelBase)titleViewModel;
        message.Reply(true);

        IsLoading = false;
    });
}

public async void Receive(StartGameRequest message)
{
    IsLoading = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Content = (ViewModelBase)gameViewModel;
        message.Reply(true);

        IsLoading = false;
    });
}
```

The `void Receive(RequestMessage<T>)` methods are part of the `IRecipient<T>` interface, but there doesn't seem to be any problem with the fact that they're `async void`. The methods are being invoked, it's just the `Task.Run()` body that is not reachable on browser.

Comment: You are using `async void`. That is not awaitable and might not run at all.

Comment: Removing it changes nothing

Comment: What do you mean with "removing"?